# substr and strip_tags character issue and solution

Tags: php

I'm calling same text for php but result is chracter problem. e.g;

`"<div class="open"><?php echo ex_substr(180); ?></div>"`

and run the function

```
function ex_substr($char) {

    $title= get_the_excerpt($post->ID);

    $title= strip_tags(substr($title,0,$char));

    echo $title."...";
}
```

At the end of the text content,there are character problems for example: �

I'm very new about php.

Comment: is that the end of the function is is there a `}` that you forgot.  Oh, and welcome to SO and the PHP world.

Comment: No I did not forget it. I just did not write.

Comment: Typically issues like this have to do with either the encoding of the input and/or the encoding of the page.  Where is this text from ( for example a database ) and what encoding are you using on the page `UTF-8`?

Comment: input encoding and database is UTF-8. I thought the problem was in the code.

Comment: No, it's probably with the data and the output encoding on your site.  Even with UTF-8 on the DB, I found crap in there myself,  for example when I create XML files, it destroys them and in the DB it looks like a line return.  This is what I use to remove those maybe it will work for you `$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);`

Comment: Can you show an example piece of text and how it's being incorrectly transformed?

Comment: A problem that only occurs at the end of the article with a length of 180 characters. more precisely at the end of the writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I said in the comments when you see weird stuff like � you probably have some weird non UTF-8 characters in there.

While I am by no means an expert at encodings ( typical I just remove that junk )  This is what I use to deal with them

```
  preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

Here is a PHP sandbox you can try it in.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/695ad38ae46ef5a142102dd6150fd84279b1a058

```
 $string ='this is a string �';
 echo preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

Output

```
  'this is a string '
```

You can smack it with `trim($string)` if that extra space at the end bugs you.

Another trick is to replace it with a space .  and then remove any multiple spaces.  That way if it's between words it doesn't just jam them together.

```
 $string ='this is a�string';
 $string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', ' ', $string);

 echo trim( preg_replace('/\s{2, }/', ' ', $string)); //replace 2 or more spaces with a single space.
```

Even when the DB charset set to UTF-8 I occasionally get weird stuff in my DB.  We have a lot of content that is scrapped off the web so who knows what that crap is.

This is sort of a "rudimentary"  way to fix it, but if you're not worried about loosing those characters than it should be fine. I should study up more on encoding issues, now that I don't have PHP6 to fix all that for me.

( PS from what i understand PHP6 was supposed to have more support for multi=byte strings, but because of the short comings of C it all fell apart, which is why we went from PHP5 to PHP7 )

Hope that helps.

Comment: My database character sets "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" ... I don't know what the problem with that part. but I will try your writing now.

Comment: Mine are `utf8_general_ci` which I think is just the default.

Comment: @Barloa - what Database do you use ( Mysqli, PDO etc )

Comment: I do remember setting the connection charset one time to fix something like this, but that must have been like 4 years ago, I cant recall exactly what it was.

Comment: database is mysql. I recently made migration and redirect. the settings may be corrupted.i don't remember. but your solution worked ! I checked most of the posts. the problem is gone now. thank you !!

Comment: Here I found it, you could try connecting using this  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php  if you use mysqli  `$mysql->setCharset('utf8')`  Had to remote into work and look at some old code ... lol ... anyway I think it's acceptable to remove and replace them in the DB, you should do a export of the table, and then write a script to go through and clean them up.   That way you wont have to deal with them on the application side, especially if you migrated from a DB with a different charset.

Comment: You know what I mean, if this is an "artifact" of migrating, then likely there is no coding issue, just some data that needs to be corrected.  So if the problem wont persist ( adding new data is fine ), then like I said the best thing would be backup the table, and clean the data up, then you don't have to repeatedly deal with it in your application.

Comment: yes.. I currently have an english character sets problem with your php solution. I will try to say the other.

Comment: I am setting the sql directly in UTF-8. after taking the backup.

Comment: Yea It may try to remove other stuff, we use that replacement for data that is OCR read from PDF's so they are pretty messy to begin with.  Like I said I hate encoding issues, such a pain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$title= strip_tags(substr($title,0,$char));
```

instead of

```
$title= mb_substr($title,0,$char);
```

The problem is completely resolved when I use it.